# Criptografia AES e RSA compatível com bibliotecas PHP

Tags: asp.net, criptografia, rsa, aes

Estou iniciando um trabalho de teste de comunicação com um webservice, e essa interação inclui os protocolos de criptografias AES e RSA. Entretanto, o site que possui o webservice (followzup) só apresenta exemplos em PHP e Java.
Como fazer esse teste? Qual protocolo devo utilizar primeiro?

Comment: Não conheço ASP.NET, mas talvez a [documentação das funções de criptografia do .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ss79b2x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) te ajude. Se precisar de mais ajuda em alguma aplicação (protocolo) em particular, favor [edit] a pergunta com os detalhes relevantes.

Answer (score 1):

Comece lendo a documentação das classes [RSACryptoProviderService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) e [AES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx).

Aqui exemplos, tirados do próprio MSDN, de como usá-las:

**Criptografia RSA**:

```
static public byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] DataToEncrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
{        
    byte[] encryptedData;           
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {

        RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
        encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(DataToEncrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
    }
    return encryptedData;
}
```

**Decriptografia RSA**:

```
static public byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] DataToDecrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
{
    byte[] decryptedData;
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {

        RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
        decryptedData = RSA.Decrypt(DataToDecrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
    }

    return decryptedData;
}
```

E para utilizar:

```
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    byte[] dataToEncrypt = ByteConverter.GetBytes("MEU DADO PARA CRIPTOGRAFAR");    
    byte[] encryptedData = RSAEncrypt(dataToEncrypt, RSA.ExportParameters(false), false); // Criptografa
    byte[] decryptedData = RSADecrypt(encryptedData, RSA.ExportParameters(true), false); // Descriptografa
}
```

---

**Criptografia AES**:

```
static byte[] AesEncrypt(string plainText, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
{
    byte[] encrypted;

    using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        aesAlg.Key = key;
        aesAlg.IV = IV;
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                }
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    return encrypted;

}
```

**Decriptografia AES**:

```
static string AesDecrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
{
    string plaintext = null;
    using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        aesAlg.Key = key;
        aesAlg.IV = IV;

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
        using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
        {
            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    return plaintext;
}
```

E para utilizar:

```
using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
{
    byte[] encrypted = AesEncrypt("MEU DADO PARA CRIPTOGRAFAR", myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
    string decrypted = AesDecrypt(encrypted, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
}
```